# Mac OS Mavericks. JDK installer can't see JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, macos

Yesterday I bought a new Mac and now trying to configure on them JDK 7.

Apple JDK 6 package is currently installed on this path:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`

`/usr/libexec/java_home` and `echo $JAVA_HOME` print also this

`/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`

In my ˜/.bash_profile I have also `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java)`.

Also I have installed `JRE7`. So `java -version` print this:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

But! Now I'm trying to launch JDK7 and have this error:

```
sudo sh Downloads/java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64.sh
Password:
Extracting the installer archive...
Extracting the installer runtime...
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...
Extracting the installer resources...
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...
Extracting the installer metadata...
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...

Welcome to GlassFish installer

Using the user defined JAVA_HOME : /usr
Entering setup...
```

This is important, because if now I will start installing JDK it will not locate in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` directory.

Comment: Set JAVA_HOME to the home directory of JDK 7. Don't use the indirection with `/usr/libexec/java`.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I have no JDK 7(but want to install). I have JRE 7 and JDK 6. That's all.

Comment: The JRE also has a Home. But now that you say it, I have never installed Java on OS X using a shell script. I used the standard installer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik JRE I have installed with standard installer. But JDK installers provide only in shell script.

Comment: But I have installed several JDKs by now, including JDK 8 EA, and never had to run a shell script.

Comment: You are installing *Java EE* SDK, not Java SE. That's a totally different story. Are you sure that is what you actually want? JEE SDK is not what the term JDK refers to, and is not even a Java Runtime.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Right. Now I try to install Java EE SDK with JDK. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-7-sdk-with-jdk-u45-2066865.html

But if I want to install this, for first I need to install JRE 7.

Comment: So have you already tried it after setting `JAVA_HOME` the JRE7's location of the Java home?

Comment: Yes. It stores in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`. But in `bin` directory isn't `jar` file. So I have error that I have no jar file in this file path. This JRE downloaded and installed from oracle.com from *.dmg installer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this, too. Seems that trying to install [Java EE 7 Development Kit Bundles with JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-7-sdk-with-jdk-u45-2066865.html) from [Java EE 7 SDK Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) doesn't work. The shell script installer appears to depend on things that aren't in the "plugin" JRE.

Instead, try installing the Java Development Kit first and then running the unbundled EE SDK as follows:

1. [Java SE Development Kit 7 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) - Download and install Mac OS X x64 Java SE Development Kit
2. [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 7 SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-downloads-1956236.html) - Download and run the Unix / Linux / Mac OS X version.